# A question about Vue.js source code in function _createElement()

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In `_createElement`, I want to ask whether `data.is` is same to the `v-bind:is`?

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/0baa129d4cad44cf1847b0eaf07e95d4c71ab494/src/core/vdom/create-element.js#L64

Why `tag = data.is`?

Thanks for every respondent!

[image: Picture of the code]

Comment: they are not the same

Comment: They are not exactly the same. They are alternate methods converging into the same point: setting the `tag` used as root element for the component. What's your use case? What are you trying to achieve? Ref: *"Why "tag = data.is""*. Because inside a render function one of the methods by which you can set the tag is using an `is` in the `data` object provided to the `createElement` function. This is why (technically), when you specify a Vue component as `createElement`'s first argument it renders that component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment in the code suggests, that line is specifically to handle the case where `is` is included inside an object `v-bind`. e.g.:

```html
<component v-bind="{ is: 'button' }">Button</component>
```

You can see this for yourself by setting a breakpoint in your browser on that line. I'm using Webpack and Chrome and the relevant file appears under `webpack:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js` in the *Sources* tab. Quick search for `_createElement` and click in the margin to set a breakpoint.

In the example above the `is` value is intended to be used as the `tag`, whereas `component` is just a dummy tag that can be discarded.

The syntax above is equivalent to:

```html
<component is="button">Button</component>
```

or:

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

However, neither of these two examples will go into the relevant `if` section. In these other two cases the `tag` is already resolved correctly prior to this point.

Comment: Thank you very much